# get_custom_logo and get_bloginfo dont work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new at developing with wp. And I would like to know why
`get_custom_logo();` and `get_bloginfo( 'description' );`
aren't shown in my view. They are described in my header.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `echo` before the function.

Like this

```
echo get_bloginfo( 'description' )
```